# Time evolution of operators in linear response theory (Kubo formula)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, perturbation-theory, many-body

I am reading the following book

> [Many-body quantum theory in condensed matter physics book by Henrik Bruus and Karsten Flensberg](https://b-ok.asia/book/18341414/d3440c)

This book mainly focuses on time-independent Hamiltonians only. When Hamiltonian $H$ is time-independent, the time evolution operator is simply $U\left(t,t'\right) =e^{-i H\left(t-t'\right)}$. In the fifth chapter, the authors introduce retarded correlation function

$$C_{AB}^R\left(t,t'\right)=-i\theta(t-t')\left\langle \left[A(t),B(t')\right] \right\rangle=-i\theta(t-t')\frac{1}{Z}Tr\left[e^{-\beta H}\left[A(t),B(t')\right]\right] \tag{5.42}$$

Further they prove that when $H$ is time-independent, $C_{AB}^R\left(t,t'\right)$ depend upon only time difference $t-t'$. This entire proof depends upon the fact that evolution operator is given by $U\left(t,t'\right) =e^{-i H\left(t-t'\right)}$.

In the sixth chapter, the authors introduce linear response theory when Hamiltonians also have a external time-dependent perturbation $H'(t)$. Further they calculate time dependent expectation value of an operator $A$ denoted by $\left\langle A \right\rangle \left(t\right)$ by going into the interaction picture
$$
\delta\left\langle A \right\rangle \left(t\right)\equiv\left\langle A \right\rangle \left(t\right) - \left\langle A \right\rangle_0  =\int_{t_0}^{\infty} dt' C_{AH'}^R\left(t,t'\right) \tag{6.7}
$$
with
$$
C_{AH'}^R\left(t,t'\right) =-i\theta\left(t-t'\right)\left\langle \left[\hat{A}(t),\hat{H}'\left(t'\right)\right] \right\rangle_0 \tag{6.8}
$$
here $\hat{A}(t)$ is the operator in interaction picture.

So far so good!

Next, they take a perturbation of the form
$$H'\left(t\right)=Bf\left(t\right) \tag{6.9}$$
where $B$ is a **time-independent operator** and $f\left(t\right)$ is a **time-dependent** function which is **not an operator**. They say that in this case, $C_{AH'}^R\left(t,t'\right)$ can be written as
$$
C_{AH'}^R\left(t,t'\right)=C_{AB}^R\left(t,t'\right)f\left(t'\right)=C_{AB}^R\left(t-t'\right)f\left(t'\right) \tag{6.10}
$$
In other words, they are saying that $C_{AB}^R\left(t,t'\right)$ depend upon only time difference $t-t'$. I am confused that how can we say this because now the total Hamiltonian is time dependent as it has term $H'\left(t\right)=Bf\left(t\right)$ in it.